# Issue passing parameter values to another method in class

Tags: c#

I have created a Windows Forms and have a grid on it that I am trying to populate with the data below that returns
from proc Get_Details on Sybase.

But I am getting the errors below for each of the fields, when I try to refer to them in the method FillScreen().

The type or namespace name '_PrId' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name '_DoId' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name '_Sta' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name '_PlId' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name '_TRequest' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)

I know I could the method FillScreen() in another class and call it that way but just wondering is it possible to do it the way I am trying
all in the same class.

Any more details/info needed pls let me know.

```
    void CheckForJob(DateTime startDate)
    {
        bool closeConnection = false;
        AseConnection con = null;
        try
        {
            con = DatabaseUtil.GetCon();
            if (con.Transaction == null)
                closeConnection = true;

            int _PrId;
            int _DoId;
            int _Sta;
            int _PlId;
            DateTime _TRequest;

            using (var sqlCmd = new AseCommand("Get_Details", con))
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Timerequested", AseDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;

                DataSet dataset;
                DatabaseUtil.FetchData(sqlCmd, out dataset, con);
                if (dataset.Tables.Count > 0)
                {

                    foreach (DataRow tmpRow in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        _PrId = (int)tmpRow["PR_ID"];
                        _DoId = (int)tmpRow["DO_ID"];
                        _Sta = (short)tmpRow["STA"];
                        _PlId = (int)tmpRow["PL_ID"];
                        _TRequest = (DateTime)tmpRow["T_REQUEST"];

                        FillScreen(_PrId, _DoId, _Sta, _PlId, _TRequest);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (closeConnection) con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Failed getting details from Get_Details", ex);
        }
    }

    public void FillScreen(int _PrId, int _DoId, int _Sta, int _PlId, DateTime _TRequest);
    {
            object[] aRow = new object[5];
            aRow[0] = _PrId;
            aRow[1] = _DoId;
            aRow[2] = _Sta;
            aRow[3] = _PlId;
            aRow[4] = Convert.ToDateTime(__TRequest).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");

            grdDocs.Rows.Add(aRow);
    }
```

Comment: This : `int _Sta;` Doesn't match this : `_Sta = (short)tmpRow["STA"];`.

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Remove the semicolon at the end of the method FillScreen and then check if you have still errors.

Comment: The specific error message you're getting, "The type or namespace name '_PrId' could not be found" means that you somewhere have something like `new _PrId`, can you please post the actual code? The semicolon at the end of your `FillScreen` declaration should give you a bunch of *other* errors as well, which also leads me to think this is not your real code but just a typed up example similar (but not identical) to what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the semicolon in your function

```
public void FillScreen(int _PrId, int _DoId, int _Sta, int _PlId, DateTime _TRequest);
    {.....
```

Comment: There is a specific close reason for Typographical errors. No need to give answers for these little errors of no value for future readers.

Comment: Ok, I'll have it in mind... so the correct procedure in these cases is to comment and then asking a moderator to close it for Typographical errors?

Comment: Just vote to close. Do not ping a moderator for this.

Comment: @karkazz, thanks for that, that looks like it sorted it, apologies of a simple one, just shows a fresh pair of eyes is always good, can look at something too long.